# Or-ing relationships in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a number of many to many relationships between two tables with conditionals representing different roles.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :course_mentors, :conditions => { :type_str => "mentor" }, :class_name => CourseUser
  has_many :mentors, :through => :course_mentors, :source => :user

  has_many :course_enrollees, :conditions => { :type_str => "enrollee" }, :class_name => CourseUser
  has_many :enrollees, :through => :course_enrollees, :source => :user
  ...
end
```

To retrieve the contents of one of the associations on its own I can simply do @course.enrollees, @course.mentors etc. However sometimes it would be convenient to be able to get both enrollees and mentors together.

I have many different associations which makes it impractical to create additional associations for each combination of single associations. One can always do

```
(@course.enrollees + @course.mentors).sort
```

however this results in two requests to the database and possibly duplicate entries.

I have also investigated the `merge` function on associations, however this just returns an empty relation.

What is the best rails like way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a general association to CourseUser inside your Course model:

```
has_many :course_users
```

And then put a scope inside CourseUser model:

```
scope :of_type, lambda {|types| where(:type_str => types)}
```

Then you can access it via:

```
my_course = Course.first
my_course.course_users.of_type([:mentor, :enrollee])
```

Comment: This is *perfect*, exactly the sort of thing we were looking for. How does this work under the hood though? Is one db request made or n for n different relations?

Comment: Now getting the error: undefined method `of_type' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd8292bd460>

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok kinda sorted it, I was using another through relation called :users rather than the relation :course_users to the join table.

Now the code which you gave returns the objects of the join model rather than the model on the other side of the relation (user). How can I do this?